# Qt/C++ - Convert string timestamp to uint

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a date but my timestamp is in a char*.

So I'm trying to convert to int but with atoi() or toInt() I don't get it.

```
qDebug() << atoi("1478790756754"); /* give 2147483647 */

QString tmp = "1478790756754";
qDebug() << tmp.toInt(); /* give 0 */
```

The aim is to get the date, with dateTime.setTime_t() for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timestamp seems to be in the *milliseconds since 1.1.1970* format. This obviously doesn't fit a 32-bit integer, as is the `int` type on your architecture.

The solution is simple: convert to a type with larger value range, i.e. `long long`:

```
QString tmp = "1478790756754";
QDateTime date = QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(tmp.toLongLong());
```

`QString`'s conversion functions also have an out parameter pointer to `bool`. You can pass a bool variable and test it to check if the conversion was successful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `atoll` instead. Please note the limits in [`<climits>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/).